# Interactive emoticons on cloud page - IF/ELSE IF statements

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

As seen in the below picture, if I select emoticon 2 (sad face) in an email, on the cloud page, it displays blue emoticons up until emoticon 2.

But I want to write a code that says, if I select emoticon 2 in an email, it only displays that specific emoticon in blue.

[image]

Here's the current code:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your condition from:

```
IF @Surveyrating >= 3
```

To:

```
IF @Surveyrating  == 3
```

You can see more details on logical operators and other Ampscript language elements in [this documentation page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm)

Comment: I tried '=' before too, it didn't work. But then I tried '==' based on the link you shared, and it worked fine. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I missed the double '=' mark